# Can i use mongodb atlas data api with react js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

> "I m using mongo db data api with react when i fetching the data its giving me the cors error. So can i use mongo db data api with react or not"

Answer (score 0):

You can run you're react application in insecure chrome browser mode to avoid cross error

Run below command in terminal

open -na Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/temporary-chrome-profile-dir --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials